# Using Asp.net Identity in with Entity Framework throws Could not load type .Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

```
public EmployeeDTO AuthenticateEmployee(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var userLogin = UnitOfWork.UserLoginRepository.Get(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userLogin == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

            // this throws an error.
            var user = userManager.Find("username", "password");
        }
    }
}
```

Results in error:

> Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I'm using EF 6.0, `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` Ver 2.0.

I couldn't perform any action based on EF using Identity is there anything I have to do, my EDMX is in another class library. I think its a DLL issue.

Please help me to use identity with EF.

I have gone through [Msdn](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`IndexAttribute` is one of the new things included in EF 6.1. So the problem is that you're referencing the wrong EF version (6.0). Please reference 6.1 in your project.

Look at [EF Version History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253).

Comment: Thanks its works . But I have Connection issue but it works fine with my repository .

Comment: Error A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

Comment: This is another question. How are you specifying the connection string used by your context? Is ti correct?

Comment: var user = userManager.Find("username", "password"); Identity couldn't find the database . In my appConfig.  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VofoxManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VofoxHRDataModel.csdl|res://*/VofoxHRDataModel.ssdl|res://*/VofoxHRDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.******;initial catalog=VofoxManagement;user id=**;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Still Identity doesn't find the Db.

Comment: IdentityDbContext db = new IdentityDbContext("VofoxManagementEntities"); I do it like this way , but I thinks is not correct.

Comment: That's correct. However, try to specify the connection string as the parameter itself, i.e. not the connection string name, bu the full connection string as it appears on web.config ("metada:..."). Just to make sure the conn string is right, and the SQL Server is reachable. (I always use Code First so i'm not very expert on the model first connection string)

Comment: Second time I use this answer and it still works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error but all the EntityFramework references in packages.config were pointing to the latest EF version (in my case 6.1.3). I unloaded the offending project where the error was occuring from and noticed the Hint paths for EF were old. After updating them, they worked fine.

Old References:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Updated working references:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Thanks @sarin for your help, I will up voted the answer, but couldn't accept you as answer as it has one already,

Comment: Hi sarin, I already have the references updated. and its still not working. I am using Mysql. Gives me the same error "Could not load type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute.." I my packages.config i have     <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0"