# Entity Framework IndexAttribute error when Using MySql with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, gacutil

I want my mvc application to connect to `MySQL` database and I have done the following steps since morning but am missing something.

1. Installed `MySQL` Connector for `.Net` (Connector `ODBC` 5.3)
2. Installed (`MySQL` for Visual Studio 1.2.6)
3. Followed the tutorial 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider#configure-entityframework-to-work-with-a-mysql-database

   - nuget installed entityframework 6.1.3

now when I run the website and try to register, it crashed saying

> Could not load type
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

my .csproj file contains

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="MySql.Data">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.9\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MySql.Data.Entity.6.9.9\lib\net45\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

My application references include:

- EntityFramework
- EntityFramework.SqlServer
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF6

I also added

- `MySql.Data.Entity` from the assemblies in (`MySQL` for Visual Studio 1.2.6)

I am new to both MVC and `MySQL`. So, don't have a clear picture of what could go wrong.

**UPDATE** Someone suggested on another post that i need to remove it from the gacutil. Now gacutil is saying i need admin privileges to remove an assembly which already have.. Is there a work around? is this the right-solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Asp.net Identity in with Enitity Framework throws Could not load type .Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568896/using-asp-net-identity-in-with-enitity-framework-throws-could-not-load-type-sch)

Comment: Thanks Ashish for a quick response, but i couldnt figure out how to reference 6.1.3 instead of 6.0.0.0? in my .csproj its pointing to the latest one i suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the update i was trying was correct. So the problem was that i had a duplicate EntityFramework dll with version 6.0.0.0 in the gac. And to do that i had to **right-click** on command prompt and choose "run as administrator" and then try uninstalling the dll.

BOOM!! This was what i was missing.